# To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

While i test Admob in simulator, it throws below error

> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];

My Code

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"8de66ecc3525495d";

bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

GADRequest *request = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
request.testing = YES;
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

Guide me to archive it. Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At finally fix the bug friends..

I made mistake to generate **adUnitID**. So only i cannot get ad view.

Now get one **adUnitID** from xxxx site for testing. And its working fine..

```
adUnitID = @"a14dccd0fb24d45";
```

Thanks for All Supporters.

Answer (score 26):

You have to add your test devices. With Swift, just replace

```
bannerView.load(GADRequest())
```

with

```
let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
bannerView.load(request)
```

If you have an iPhone, then run the application too and it will tell you the ID.

To get test ads on this device, call: `request.testDevices = @[@"HERE IS THE ID"];`

ID added:

```
let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = ["PUT HERE THE ID", kGADSimulatorID]
bannerView.load(request)
```

Comment: the real question is WHY google samples are wrong, with no correct comments, and WHY suggestions in debug info are misleading...

Comment: In the current version of swift, loadRequest has been changed to load.

Comment: Hello, sorry can you tell me in what place of my code I need to use: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = ["YOUR IDENTIFIER PRINTED ON DEBUGGER"] ?

Answer (score 6):

Since the newest update the `request.testDevices` has been replaced with:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers
```

I have gotten it to work with this:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [(kGADSimulatorID as! String)]
```

[EDIT]

In my app delegate I am using this code:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
    // use this for production 
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
    // use this for testing 
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [ kGADSimulatorID ]
        
    return true
}
```

This is for Swift 5, iOS 13 and Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.58.0)

Comment: To avoid this log message only use this with your own ID something like this:

GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = ["bd69106a84e845a3b46dd17deef75fe3"]

Comment: Hello, sorry can you tell me in what place of my code I need to use: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = ["YOUR IDENTIFIER PRINTED ON DEBUGGER"] ?

Comment: @VyacheslavBakinkskiy It lives in your app delegate. You should use it instead of starting the non-test code. I've added my app delegate to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works for  me:

```
(GADRequest *)request {
  GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
  // Make the request for a test ad. Put in an identifier for the simulator as well as any devices
  // you want to receive test ads.
  request.testDevices = @[
    // TODO: Add your device/simulator test identifiers here. Your device identifier is printed to
    // the console when the app is launched.
    GAD_SIMULATOR_ID
  ];
  return request;//thanks
}
```

Comment: I replaced  GAD_SIMULATOR_ID with request.KGADrequest and it worked for me ^^

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this:

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

// Make the request for a test ad. Put in an identifier for
// the simulator as well as any devices you want to receive test ads.
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
[gAdBannerView loadRequest:request];
```

where I define

```
// Constant for getting test ads on the simulator using the testDevices method.
#define GAD_SIMULATOR_ID @"Simulator"
```

Comment: Again Same Error Came.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why you are getting always this error. One question: did your banner get displayed...? Or don't you see any banner?

Comment: I didn't get any banner, shows empty screen only. Actually i run this code in Simulator. Is this any problem ??

Comment: Try looking at origin and size of the frame of your bannerView_, maybe it's offscreen (it did happen to me, I was using landscape orientation  but coordinates of the frame was for portrait, so the view was offscreen). I have also notice that your unitID is quite different from mine... Mine is in the form of gAdBannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-1234567890123456/1234567890". Also set your delegate

Comment: Also set your delegate "[bannerView_ setDelegate:self];" and implement "adViewDidReceiveAd:" and "adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError;" to check what is happening.

Comment: I made mistake to generate adUnitID. So only i cannot get ad view. Now get temporary ID from xxxx site for testing. Now its working. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this. Works for me even in the simulator. I got the error, but it isn't an error, I searched extensively and found out that it is more of an informative message.

The main point will be to get the real ad showing when the testing mode is set to NO, and a "Success, you are now ready to travel the ad galaxy" message when the testing mode is set to YES. Therefore, if you have either of the results in the app, it should be fine. :)

My code is as follows:

```
GADBannerView *bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

bannerView_.adUnitID = GOOGLE_UNIT_ID;

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

bannerView_.delegate = self;

bannerView_.rootViewController = self;

// Make the request for a test ad. Put in an identifier for
// the simulator as well as any devices you want to receive test ads.
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,
                       nil];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

I did not set the testing as YES. My Google AdMobs SDK version is 6.5.1

Since you were mentioning that you need help for production, it should not be set to testing mode anyway, so you should probably run it without test mode.

Looking at the question of whether running on simulator or real device does not matter, it should run on both the devices. I set the delegate to self in my codes, and therefore if you do the same, you can use the methods:

```
- (void) adView: (GADBannerView*) view didFailToReceiveAdWithError: (GADRequestError*) error
- (void) adViewDidReceiveAd: (GADBannerView*) view
```

These can help you in checking if you have received the ads at all, even when running in simulator.

Hope this helps! :)