# Admob iOS, show ads on test device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, admob

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"MY_SIMULATOR_IDENTIFIER",
                       @"MY_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER",
                       nil];
```

In Google's documentation, it says pass "MY_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER" to see test ads on a real device. I tried the UDID and the UUID, but it doesn't seem to be working. Does any one know what they are referring to when they say "MY_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER"?

When I run the application it says:

> To get test ads on this device, call:r.testDevices = @[
>   @"cc61ecab38c2f408f90800c3ea08fb6d" ];

But I don't know what "cc61ecab38c2f408f90800c3ea08fb6d" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `AdSupport.framework` in project and use---

```
NSString *uniqueString= [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   @"MY_SIMULATOR_IDENTIFIER",uniqueString,
                   nil];
```

Comment: You need to md5 the uniqueString for it to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the UDID of your device. You can see the device identifier xcode->Organiser->Devices, tap to the device in the list to check UDID.[image]

Comment: when i run my app on device , log displays use this cc61ecab38c2f408f90800c3ea08fb6d this test ads but this is not my UDID

Comment: Did you implement the delegate methods. Please implement and check the error.

Comment: [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527478/to-get-test-ads-on-this-device-call-request-testdevices-nsarray-arraywithob)

Comment: This answer is wrong. The string you add to the testDevices in **NOT** the UDID.